# Can I write Cortana Skills to control my computer like change brightness or put my computer to sleep?

Tags: cortana

All the cortana bots seem to be sandboxed with limited capabilities. Is there any way I can write system files or chagne system configuration through these bots ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that kind of control you should create a UWP project and use [Voice Command Definition API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/voicecommands/launch-a-foreground-app-with-voice-commands-in-cortana) cortana skills are good for ordering pizza or book a flight, something that needs to be done over internet with a third-party API

Answer (score 0):

Not without a Win32 Application that communicates with the Cortana Skill via the web.

What you can do is write script and but them in a folder under C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
than you can run them like "Hey Cortana open custom script"